# Libgdx: listen for click on TextField

Tags: libgdx

I am trying to remove the `placeholder-text` I put inside my `TextField` (instructions etc) when a user clicks them, but I am getting the error:

> `com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.TextField is not an enclosing class`

My code:

```
final TextField searchField = new TextField("Who are you looking for?", newSkin);
                searchField.setFocusTraversal(false);
                searchField.setTextFieldListener(new TextField.TextFieldClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
                        super.clicked(event, x, y);
                        searchField.clear();
                    }
                });
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: You put new TextField.TextFieldClickListener, which doesn't exist.

Comment: @tenfour04 but it's in the api if u Google it. And shows up using intellisense in Android studio. Can you please help me with how to check for a click on a text field then? A normal click listener does not work.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. The reason you can't instantiate it from the TextField class itself is that it's not a static class. Use `searchField` instead of `TextField` when instantiating it so you're instantiating it from an object instead of from the class.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Hmm that did not seem to work. Could you try and if you succeed post it as answer? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are confusing [TextField.TextFieldListener](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/TextField.TextFieldListener.html) and [TextField.TextFieldClickListener](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/TextField.TextFieldClickListener.html).

In your code you want to use `setTextFieldListener` but with the `TextFieldClickListener` parameter, so compiler cannot resolve it properly.
You may simply use `ClickListener` instead:

```
    searchField.addListener(new ClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
            super.clicked(event, x, y);
            searchField.setText("");
        }
    });
```

Also, note, that you should set the empty string as a text since [`clear()` method](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/Actor.html#clear--) is used for:

> Removes all actions and listeners on this actor.

and this is definitely not what you are looking for

Comment: Im pretty sure this is the first thing I tried, and it didnt work. Ill try again just to make sure!

Comment: do not forget to remove `setTextFieldListener` as it is in your snippet. Otherwise, it would remove all other listeners.

Comment: @iQue, so did you check that? I'm really curious)

Comment: Works perfectly, sorry for late response, been too busy to try :) No idea why this didnt work the first time I tried it. Thanks!

Comment: @iQue nice to hear that)